# Exit Code 0 - no output - web-scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I want to read data from a web page with Python, but I get the following in the console:

```
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Actually, the HTML code of this class should be displayed.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/nordrhein-westfalen/koeln/wohnung-kaufen?enteredFrom=one_step_search').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
object = soup.find('li', class_ ='result-list__listing result-list__listing--xl-new')
print(object)
```

Comment: If it is html why are you using "lxml" as your parser?

Comment: If you get a None, it means soup doesn't find anything that match what you want. Maybe your website doesn't return the same stuff you see when you inspect the HTML, so it doesn't find anything.

Anyway, that question lacks sufficient details for us to answer why that's the case. Please add the complete code (e.g., what's the URL you are using, at least?)

Comment: Adding to what Yubo said, a lot of websites generate content using JS. BeautifulSoup doesn't render JS, and won't be able to see those parts of the code.

Comment: @Squarish because lxml parser is suitable for this.

I add the full code with the URL

How can you see that it is generated by JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website uses the captcha mechanism to check whether requests are coming from a legit browser or not and filters them accordingly. You can try using Selenium to solve the issue.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Create an instance of the WebDriver using the configured browser options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service= Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Open the website URL in the browser
url = 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/nordrhein-westfalen/koeln/wohnung-kaufen?enteredFrom=one_step_search'
driver.get(url)

# Interact with the elements on the page to extract the desired data
# Find the table element
list_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li[class="result-list__listing result-list__listing--xl-new"]')))

# Iterate through the table rows, excluding the first header row
rows = bs(list_element.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'lxml')
print(rows)
```

Here's the selenium counterpart of your code.